Single pole light switch with three incoming wires that does not power any outlets, want to add new light

This is the wire setup in a guest bedroom single pole light switch. Three incoming wires. One black and one red are backstabbed. Another black is connected around the side terminal. The house was built in early 80s so other rooms have switched outlets. This light switch is hot but does not power any outlets in the bedroom. What I think the previous owner did was remove the red from the switch and made it constantly hot with the backstab. Is this a common setup? What I'd like to do is install a ceiling light into the bedroom and use this switch.
Can anyone shed light on what that might look like and what I would do with the rest of the wires in here? My thought is to

remove the backstabs due to safety reasons
cap the red (assuming the other end is capped in an always-hot outlet)
pigtail all original wiring to the incoming line for constant power
connect new ceiling light to load terminal
use a double gang box for more room


Does anyone see an issue with the proposed design? Any advice much appreciated!


The red should be the switched hot controlling the light.
There should be one incoming black always hot and the second black is powering something(an outlet?) else as an always hot.
If it does not control a ceiling light now, then it must control an outlet.  Most likely the top half of an outlet, with the bottom half always hot.
Since you have power at the switch, you just need a /2 cable(black and white plus ground) to go to the ceiling light from the switch.  The black connected to the top screw and the white connected to the whites in the back.

Thank you for the reply. I tested all the outlets in the room with the switch off and they are all still hot so that's why the red is confusing to me. Could I simply disconnect the whole middle wire in my diagram and cap it, and then do as you suggest to connect my ceiling light? I'd like to clean up the box as much as possible.

@KMF   It goes somewhere.  Can cap it and then look around the house to see what does not work.  Switches usually control stuff in the room, but the odd one will control something in another room/outside.  It does look like the red would control one half of an outlet, and black the other half as always hot.

Could I just cap off the two right wires in my diagram? This switch has been off 99.9% of the time in the 3 years I've been in my house and I haven't noticed any light or outlet not functioning. My thought is to a) make a double gang box to give more space b) cap off the right two wires c) bring in fourth wire for ceiling light and wire as you suggested with new black on top terminal and new white connected to uncapped incoming white.

@KMF  The right side cable is powering an outlet.  The left is your power cable, the only the middle is unknown, since it is both switched and always hot.  Can cap off all the wires on the middle, red/black/and white.
